# Pre-clearance in Dublin available on Aer Lingus EDI - DUB - SFO flight?

Tags: dublin, pre-clearance

Can I use US Pre-clearance in Dublin if my flight originates in Edinburgh, has a layover in Dublin and ends in San Francisco on Aer Lingus?

Basically, Dublín is my transiting airport

Comment: You must pass pre-clearance at DUB. Whether it's your origin or a transit stop (only if directly flying to the US from that point) on your way to the US. Have traveled several times through there.

Answer (score 1):

[Dublin Airport FAQ](https://www.dublinairport.com/flight-information/travelling-to-usa/faqs) states :

> #### Do I have to go through US Preclearance for a connecting flight?
>
> If you are travelling from Dublin to the US on your connecting flight
> you can use the US Preclearance facility in Dublin and will not have
> to go through US customs when you land.
>
> If you fly from Dublin to another airport outside of the US then you
> will not use US Preclearance.

So yes, you will have to pass through Preclearance